# Query-based view that changes periodically

Tags: python, django

So i'm working on a django project for a restaurant's page and i need to make a view for a menu that changes weekly.

```
class WeeklyChangingMenu(models.Model):
     introduction_date = models.DateField()
     options = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

and then i have a **menu** view:

```
def menu(request):
    menu = WeeklyChangingMenu.objects.get(introduction_date < datetime.date.today())
    return render(request, "menu.html", {"menu":menu})
```

and i'm looking for a way to, rather than making the same query over and over, simply making the query once a week by, say, a **manage.py** command to store it and reuse the info as if it was hardcoded into the view for a week which would make it a lot easier for the database.

Comment: Sounds like you want a cache. Django has a whole section on the cache framework in the docs.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what i was looking for, i just hadn't thought of cache as what i needed for some reason